# PyQt5: Creating a flow layout that forces a fixed height

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a flow layout effect where the user can modify the width of the widget, and the size adjusts to compensate. I've looked into creating a custom layout, but the layout never increases the height to compensate for a shrinking width.

The best solution I could come up with is setting the height manually on resize, but in PyQt5 this seems to (if you rapidly try to resize the window) lock the entire window, so you cannot resize it or move it any more. It can be resized or moved programatically, but the window no longer responds to user resize/move requests.

It *seems* like a recursion error, but I can't find any recursive events being triggered, and the rest of the UI doesn't hang, just the resizing.

Here is my use case:

```
import random
import sys
import math

from PyQt5.QtGui import QPalette, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication


class ChangingHeightWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._allow_height_change = False
        self._child_widgets = []
        self._create_children(8)


    def _create_children(self, count: int):
        for i in range(count):
            # Create a panel
            new_child = QWidget()
            new_child.setFixedSize(64, 64)
            new_child.setParent(self)
            new_child.show()

            # Set the color
            pal = QPalette()
            pal.setColor(QPalette.Background, QColor(random.randint(100, 255), random.randint(100, 255), random.randint(100, 255)))
            new_child.setAutoFillBackground(True)
            new_child.setPalette(pal)

            self._child_widgets.append(new_child)

        self._move_panels()

    def _move_panels(self):
        num_per_row = max(int((self.width()) / 64), 1)

        for i in range(8):
            y = int(i / num_per_row)
            x = i % num_per_row
            self._child_widgets[i].move(x * 64, y * 64)

        num_rows = math.ceil(8 / float(num_per_row))
        min_height = num_rows * 64
        self.setFixedHeight(min_height)

    def resizeEvent(self, QResizeEvent):
        self._move_panels()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import callback_fix
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = ChangingHeightWidget()
    gui.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Is there a way to stop this locking up happening? Alternatively, is there a way to achieve this effect without needing to call setFixedHeight inside the resizeEvent?

Comment: works for me, no error. (I am using qt 5.6.0 and deleted the line `import callback_fix`)

Comment: It works for me for a short while, but if I resize it enough times, it eventually stops working. A couple of seconds of non-stop resizing normally locks it for me. I'm pretty sure it's because of doing "setFixedHeight" inside the "resizeEvent" but I can't think of another way to achieve the effect.

Comment: I cant reproduce it.. what is `callback_fix`?

Comment: Callback fix is something to make sure the error messages appear in the console. I've managed to restructure the code so that setFixedHeight is not called inside a resizeEvent, and that seems to have fixed the problem. There doesn't seem to be a way to set the height during a resize without running into some kind of recursive problem with the window manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import random
import sys
import math

from PyQt5.QtGui     import QPalette, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QListWidget


class ChangingHeightWidget(QListWidget):           # - QWidget  
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setFrameShape(self.NoFrame)           # +++
        self.setFlow(self.LeftToRight)             # +++
        self.setWrapping(True)                     # +++
        self.setResizeMode(self.Adjust)            # +++


        self._allow_height_change = False
        self._child_widgets = []
        self._create_children(8)


    def _create_children(self, count: int):
        for i in range(count):
            # Create a panel
            new_child = QWidget()
            new_child.setFixedSize(64, 64)
            new_child.setParent(self)
            new_child.show()

            # Set the color
            pal = QPalette()
            pal.setColor(QPalette.Background, QColor(random.randint(100, 255), random.randint(100, 255), random.randint(100, 255)))
            new_child.setAutoFillBackground(True)
            new_child.setPalette(pal)

            self._child_widgets.append(new_child)

        self._move_panels()

    def _move_panels(self):
        num_per_row = max(int((self.width()) / 64), 1)

        for i in range(8):
            y = int(i / num_per_row)
            x = i % num_per_row
            self._child_widgets[i].move(x * 64, y * 64)

#        num_rows = math.ceil(8 / float(num_per_row))
#        min_height = num_rows * 64
#        self.setFixedHeight(min_height)

    def resizeEvent(self, QResizeEvent):
        self._move_panels()


if __name__ == '__main__':
#    import callback_fix
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = ChangingHeightWidget()
    gui.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: I hadn't tried using a list widget, but it doesn't seem to solve the problem, because it's not forcing the height of the widget at all. Ideally, what I'm looking for is a widget that can have a fixed height, based on its width, that is updated whenever the width is changed.

Comment: @Joe Shanahan Try it : )

Comment: Oh, sorry, to clarify: I did try it, it didn't set the height properly.

Comment: @Joe Shanahan  Sorry, what kind of height?

Comment: To use the image you have as an example: you have the width set to 3 squares. To fit all the squares on screen, that requires a height of 3 squares. If you were to scale the window (horizontally) so that there were 4 squares in a row, then you'd only need a height of 2 squares to fit them all on screen. At any time, I want the height to be the exact value that fits all the children on horizontally. No more, and no less.